# Can't get Online Excel Data to Start Downloading into R

Tags: r, excel, download

I know it's poor form to try and pull data from an excel spreadsheet into R, but I am stuck trying it here. Essentially, I want to create some code that pulls some data hosted on an excel spreadsheet directly from the US Department of Education website ([https://studentaid.gov/data-center/student/portfolio][1]) for analysis so that I can just run the code to update as new data is published.

Usually, I use the readxl package to do things like this, which ends up working fairly well. However, any time I try it that on this specific data I just get a connection timeout or stuck endlessly attempting to download with no progress. Is there any way to download this specific spreadsheet? Here's a couple of the code snippets I've tried to no avail

```
library(httr, readxl)

#Trying read_xls
PORT_BY_DEBT_SIZE <- read_xls("https://studentaid.gov/sites/default/files/fsawg/datacenter/library/Portfolio-by-Debt-Size.xls")

#Trying read_xlsx
PORT_BY_DEBT_SIZE <- read.xlsx("https://studentaid.gov/sites/default/files/fsawg/datacenter/library/Portfolio-by-Debt-Size.xls")

#Trying GET
url1<-'https://studentaid.gov/sites/default/files/fsawg/datacenter/library/Portfolio-by-Debt-Size.xls'
GET(url1, write_disk(tf <- tempfile(fileext = ".xls")))
df <- read_excel(tf, 2L)
str(df)

#Trying download.file()
temp_file <- tempfile()
download.file(url = 'https://studentaid.gov/sites/default/files/fsawg/datacenter/library/Portfolio-by-Debt-Size.xls', destfile = temp_file, mode = "wb")
```

Any thoughts on this would be appreciated! I feel like I am just missing something obvious here, because it seems to me like at least one of these options should have worked.
[1]: https://studentaid.gov/data-center/student/portfolio

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing wrong with trying to pull data from an Excel file into R. Often that's the only available source for the data you need.

It seems this particular site will not allow downloads without specifying a user agent in the http request. It is easy enough to set this in `httr::GET`.

Here's a full reprex:

```r
url1 <- 'https://studentaid.gov/sites/default/files/fsawg/' |>
        paste0('datacenter/library/Portfolio-by-Debt-Size.xls')

UA <- 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64;' |> 
        paste('x64; rv:109.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/114.0')

httr::GET(url1, httr::user_agent(UA), 
          httr::write_disk(tf <- tempfile(fileext = ".xls")))
#> Response [https://studentaid.gov/sites/default/files/fsawg/datacenter/library
#> /Portfolio-by-Debt-Size.xls]
#>   Date: 2023-07-09 08:00
#>   Status: 200
#>   Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel
#>   Size: 67.6 kB
#> <ON DISK>  C:\Users\CAMERA~1\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpOqrG87\file456c4d333cd0.xls
```

We now have our file on disk and can read it as normal:

```
readxl::read_excel(tf)
#> # A tibble: 32 x 20
#>    Federal S~1 ...2  ...3  ...4  ...5  ...6  ...7  ...8  ...9  ...10 ...11 ...12
#>    <chr>       <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
#>  1 Includes o~ <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA> 
#>  2 Data Sourc~ <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA> 
#>  3 <NA>        <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA> 
#>  4 <NA>        <NA>  Less~ <NA>  5K t~ <NA>  10K ~ <NA>  20K ~ <NA>  40K ~ <NA> 
#>  5 Federal Fi~ <NA>  Doll~ Borr~ Doll~ Borr~ Doll~ Borr~ Doll~ Borr~ Doll~ Borr~
#>  6 2017        Q2    21.1~ 8.19~ 57.2~ 7.90~ 138   9.59~ 268   9.40~ 192.~ 3.89~
#>  7 2017        Q3    20.8~ 8     56.7~ 7.79~ 136.5 9.5   265   9.30~ 191.~ 3.89~
#>  8 2017        Q4    22.3~ 8.59~ 56.8~ 7.70~ 135.~ 9.40~ 268.~ 9.40~ 195.~ 4    
#>  9 2018        Q1    23.1~ 8.80~ 56.5  7.70~ 135.~ 9.40~ 266.5 9.40~ 195.~ 4    
#> 10 2018        Q2    20.6~ 8     56.5  7.79~ 137.~ 9.5   269.~ 9.5   197.~ 4    
#> # ... with 22 more rows, 8 more variables: ...13 <chr>, ...14 <chr>,
#> #   ...15 <chr>, ...16 <chr>, ...17 <chr>, ...18 <chr>, ...19 <chr>,
#> #   ...20 <chr>, and abbreviated variable name
#> #   1: `Federal Student Loan Portfolio by Borrower Debt Size`
```

<sup>Created on 2023-07-09 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

The `download.file` function, from `utils` package, can use several methods for accesing the file. To avoid 403 error you must use `curl` method.

This is my code:

```
library(utils)

xls_url <- "https://studentaid.gov/sites/default/files/fsawg/datacenter/library/Portfolio-by-Debt-Size.xls"

dest_file <- basename(xls_url)

download.file(url = xls_url,
              destfile = dest_file,
              method = "curl")
```